# Video player that does on-the-fly 30-to-60fps interpolation?

Tags: video-player

Is the a video player than can play a 30fps video at 60fps doing frame interpolation on-the-fly?

It can be done by video-conversion softwares but I wonder is there's been a player that can do it on-the-fly.

Frame/motion interpolation is a key requirement (generating a "blend" of two frames), instead of just duplicating frames to fill the gap.

- Windows, freeware upto $100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never done this, but I use mpv in Linux and figured that it can be done there, and it can! but I only found instructions and such for Linux, and I dont know how could it be done in Windows, but while searching this I found a software that does what you want, never used it so I dont know how good it is, but it seems worthwhile to give it a try, the name is SmoothVideo Project (SVP) this is its [main page](https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/Main_Page) you can download it [here](https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/Download) and has a free and pro version, but the free already does what you want so you can try it.

It is not a Video player per-se but it does work on-the-fly and works with Windows Media Player and many others players, list [here](https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/Manual:Video_players)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of instructions did you find for doing it with MPV on Linux?